# compiling my own kernel (not from linux-kernel source)

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm following the kernel tutorial from [here](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/intro.htm)

im having problems compiling my files.

i get the following errors when i try to compile:

```
main.c:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
main.c:8: error: conflicting types for ‘memcpy’                          
./include/system.h:5: note: previous declaration of ‘memcpy’ was here    
main.c: In function ‘memcpy’:                                            
main.c:12: error: ‘count’ undeclared (first use in this function)        
main.c:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once      
main.c:12: error: for each function it appears in.)                      
main.c: At top level:                                                    
main.c:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
main.c:16: error: conflicting types for ‘memset’
./include/system.h:6: note: previous declaration of ‘memset’ was here
main.c: In function ‘memset’:
main.c:19: error: ‘count’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c: At top level:
main.c:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
main.c:23: error: conflicting types for ‘memsetw’
./include/system.h:7: note: previous declaration of ‘memsetw’ was here
main.c: In function ‘memsetw’:
main.c:26: error: ‘count’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c: At top level:
main.c:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘strlen’
main.c:49: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:64: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘puts’ differ in    signedness
./include/system.h:13: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
main.c:51: warning: unused variable ‘i’
scrn.c: In function ‘scroll’:
scrn.c:24: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
./include/system.h:5: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘short unsigned int *’
scrn.c:24: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘memcpy’ from incompatible pointer type
./include/system.h:5: note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type  ‘short unsigned int *’
scrn.c: In function ‘puts’:
scrn.c:139: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ differ in signedness
./include/system.h:8: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char *’
```

My files are exact copies of the ones from the tutorial.
I can see that in main.c the functions are defined like so

`void *memcpy(void *dest,const void *src, size_t count)`

but in my system.h file they are defined like so

`extern unsigned char *memcpy(unsigned char *dest,const unsigned char *src, int count)`

C is not my primary language but i am in the process of learning it so I apologize if my question is simple but I would think that these definitions should be the same not?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I wouldn't recommend learning C and learning kernel development all in one shot.  Do some userland work in C first before you start trying to write your own kernel!

Comment: I understand your point. The tutorial is very straightforward though and I understand what it is doing. My main struggle is why the files would fail to compile from the tutorial. You would think something like function type declarations would not be a problem when you are pulling the code from a tutorial!

Comment: I'm not so sure you do understand what it is doing.  If C isn't your primary language, have you spent a lot of time working in assembly language on your target platform?  Because if you haven't done either C or assembly, then I'd be hard pressed to imagine that you can fully follow along with what the kernel is supposed to be doing.

Comment: just another reading suggestion: James Molloy's kernel development tutorial http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your issue is that `size_t` isn't the same as `int` on your platform, or `size_t` isn't specified correctly at all.  The pointer types should be OK (technically, they should match too, but on most systems `sizeof(char*) == sizeof(void*)`).

If you're developing your own kernel, you'd want to write your own `system.h`.  If you're writing both `system.h` and `main.c`, you can make them match up however you'd like.  If you look at [this page of the tutorial](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/creatingmain.htm), you'd see that header and C source both declare `memcpy` as:

```
unsigned char *memcpy(unsigned char *dest, const unsigned char *src, int count);
```

But if you download the example source files at the end of the tutorial, you find it is instead:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
```

Looking at the top of that file, you find the following comment:

```
/* bkerndev - Bran's Kernel Development Tutorial
*  By:   Brandon F. (friesenb@gmail.com)
*  Desc: Main.c: C code entry.
*
*  Notes: No warranty expressed or implied. Use at own risk. */
```

It doesn't look like you're trying to follow a tutorial, but rather that you're trying to cut and paste code from a tutorial.  That's like trying to learn to perform brain surgery by following along in a book.  You might get it to work, but if you don't really understand what you're doing... well, please do the world a favor and don't use it for anything critical.

Comment: lol. well its more like im trying to use a tutorial to understand how a kernel works a little bit better but since i don't know all the ins and outs of C im forced to just using the code already provided. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Replace size_t by int in each method definition on main.c

Comment: since an aswer was already provided and accepted.. it's no point in providing the same answer (again) much later on... :) try to focus on unanswered questions ;)

Comment: Agreed. Also, don't just provide code for your answers. Explain **why**.